# i have three places for users to log in, on the same page, how can i get all three buttons to work and three forms to process within one function

Tags: javascript, php, html

so i have three seperate login forms located on three different locations on the same page and i wantn to know how i can do this login process without having to write out three different forms and functions,  all three do the same thing but they are all in different areas, here is the example. this code works, but i have also $div2 and $div3 which are also login forms on the same page.

```
$div1 = "
      <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return false;\" onmousedown=\"dropMenu('dropmenu1')\" title=\"log in\">
        log in
      </a>
    <div id=\"dropmenu1\" class=\"dropmenus\">
        log in!<br><br>
    <form id=\"loginform1\" onsubmit=\"return false;\">
        <input type=\"text\" id=\"emaill\" placeholder=\"  enter email address\" onfocus=\"emptyElement('statusl')\" maxlength=\"88\">
        <input type=\"password\" id=\"passwordl\" placeholder=\"  enter password\" onfocus=\"emptyElement('statusl')\" maxlength=\"100\">
        <button id=\"loginbtn\" onclick=\"login()\">log in</button>
        <p id=\"statusl\"><br><br></p>
        <a href=\"/forgot_pass.php\">forgot your password?</a>
    </form>
    </div>";



function login(){
    var el = _("emaill").value;
    var pl = _("passwordl").value;
    if(el == "" || pl == ""){
        _("statusl").innerHTML = "<br>please complete the form";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("statusl").innerHTML = 'please wait...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("statusl").innerHTML = "login was unsuccessful, please try again.";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("el="+el+"&pl="+pl);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can put the JavaScript in a `.js` file. The `html` can go into a .php file and be `require()`d by your `.php` pages

Comment: You can pass a parameter to the login function, and then you can switch case this parameter within the function, will this serve your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the login button's `onclick="login()"` attribute, you can input a function parameter like this:

`onclick="login(1)"` where `1` can be a unique number for each form, ie. `$div1` has `onclick="login(1)"`, `$div2` has `onclick="login(2)"` etc...

You can then add the parameter to the login function:

`function login(formNum) {...}`

and then get the corresponding email and password for that form like this:

```
var el = _("emaill" + formNum).value;
var pl = _("passwordl" + formNum).value;
...
```

Of course you would need to change the email and password inputs' ids to include their corresponding form number like this:

`<input type="text" id="emaill1" ...>` for `$div1`, `<input type="text" id="emaill2" ...>` for `$div2`...

And also the forms', login buttons' and status paragraphs' ids in the same fashion.

In the end it would look something like this:

In Div1:

```
<form id="loginform1" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="email1" placeholder="  enter email address" onfocus="emptyElement('statusl1')" maxlength="88">
    <input type="password" id="passwordl1" placeholder="  enter password" onfocus="emptyElement('statusl1')" maxlength="100">
    <button id="loginbtn1" onclick="login(1)">log in</button>
    <p id="statusl1"><br><br></p>
    <a href="/forgot_pass.php">forgot your password?</a>
</form>
```

In Div2:

```
<form id="loginform2" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="email2" placeholder="  enter email address" onfocus="emptyElement('statusl2')" maxlength="88">
    <input type="password" id="passwordl2" placeholder="  enter password" onfocus="emptyElement('statusl2')" maxlength="100">
    <button id="loginbtn2" onclick="login(2)">log in</button>
    <p id="statusl2"><br><br></p>
    <a href="/forgot_pass.php">forgot your password?</a>
</form>
```

In Div3:

```
<form id="loginform3" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="email3" placeholder="  enter email address" onfocus="emptyElement('statusl3')" maxlength="88">
    <input type="password" id="passwordl3" placeholder="  enter password" onfocus="emptyElement('statusl3')" maxlength="100">
    <button id="loginbtn3" onclick="login(3)">log in</button>
    <p id="statusl3"><br><br></p>
    <a href="/forgot_pass.php">forgot your password?</a>
</form>
```

And Javascript:

```
function login(formNum){
    var el = _("emaill" + fornNum).value;
    var pl = _("passwordl" + fornNum).value;
    if(el == "" || pl == ""){
        _("statusl" + fornNum).innerHTML = "<br>please complete the form";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn" + fornNum).style.display = "none";
        _("statusl" + fornNum).innerHTML = 'please wait...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("statusl" + fornNum).innerHTML = "login was unsuccessful, please try again.";
                    _("loginbtn" + fornNum).style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("el="+el+"&pl="+pl);
    }
}
```